función para poner color diferente a categorias de producto en woocommerce
quiero poner de un color diferente cada categoría de woocommerce en el shortcode de mostrar categorías   [product_categories columns="4" number="0" parent="0"]  con esto me muestra las categorias y puedo modificar el color con css pero el mismo color a todas y quiero diferencias por color.
 function my_custom_category_class( $class, $category )
 { if ( $category->term_id == 389 ) { 
 $class[] = 'categoria-tablas-de-polietileno';
 } elseif ( $category->term_id == 123 ) {
 $class[] = 'categoria-lavamanos';
 } elseif ( $category->term_id == 124 ) {
 $class[] = 'categoria-ayudas-tecnicas';
 return $class;
 }
 add_filter( 'post_class', 'my_custom_category_class', 10, 2 );
 }

y luego el css
   }
   .categoria-tablas-de-polietileno {
   background-color: #3366cc !important;
   }
   .categoria-lavamanos {
   background-color: #009999 !important;
   }
   .categoria-ayudas-tecnicas {
   background-color: #a5a23c !important;

   }

y no me funciona a ver si alguien me puede ayudar

Por qué  $class[] = "clase";?? Eso no es un array... es un único string. Sería $class = "clase";. Por otro lado estás definiendo $class dentro de los if e intentando acceder a él desde fuera... necesitas declararlo arriba ANTES d elso if: $class = ""; // O clase por defecto y luego en los if lo asignas a lo que quieras. O directamente ignoras el $class y en el if simplemente usas if ( $category->term_id == 389 ) return 'categoria-tablas-de-polietileno';

Gracias Benito, la verdad es que es la primera vez que intento implementar una función y no entiendo muy bien lo que me dices que haga.

1/ el primer parámetro del filter post_class es un array, es la lista de clases que va a tener un "post" , $class[] agrega un item al array ( q para ser mas consistente debería ser $classes ); el retorno de la funcion esperado es el array de classes modificado

2/ fijate en el inspector del navegador que las categorías de producto deberían estar como classes del tipo product_cat-el-nombre-de-la-categoria, si no es así verifica que tu theme contenga un llamado a la función wc_product_class en el template tutheme/woocommerce/content-product.php. haciendo el css mas simple por ej: product_cat-lavamanos { background-color: #009999; }

3/ cosas extra en la lista de categorías usan el template tutheme/woocommerce/content-product-cat.php ahí la function es wc_product_cat_class y el filter para modificar mas especificos es 'product_cat_class' los parametros son parecidos al filter post_class: ($classes, $class, $category)

El filtro post_class espera una función cuyo argumento sean las clases preexistentes del post (un array) y esa función debe devolver así mismo un array. Por lo tanto:
function my_custom_category_class($classes)
{
    if ($category_id == 389) {
        $classes[] = 'categoria-tablas-de-polietileno';
    } elseif ($category_id == 123) {
        $classes[] = 'categoria-lavamanos';
    } elseif ($category_id == 124) {
        $classes[] = 'categoria-ayudas-tecnicas';
    }
    return $classes;
} 
add_filter('post_class', 'my_custom_category_class', 10, 2);

